# Make Inkscape UI completely dark except the document

Tags: inkscape, interface-design

I went [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/bunqu4bqt88bzqa/Inkscape+0.91+dark+theme.zip) and got myself the Inkscape Dark theme. I'm on 0.92, Windows x64.

However, I see that the vast area on the screen (not sure what it's called), where the document is placed, is still white. I'd like it to be dark like Illustrator—everything except the document should be dark.

Is it possible? I tried to look for the element in `gtkrc`, but couldn't find it—very new to Inkscape, as well as GTK.

This is what it currently looks like.

[image]

Comment: This should be handled on SuperUser.

Comment: sorry but this is a graphic design site, not tech support.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thought it would be better to ask people who work on the tool on a regular basis. I've flagged the question for moderator intervention for this to be moved to SuperUser.

Comment: @RamIyer you will find that quite a few people work with inkscape for extended periods of time. I mean i would pay for work ergonomics

Comment: I won’t migrate this question for now as I consider it to be of interest to this community and that it can be answered by it. Should the community have decided to close it, please flag it again.

Comment: @joojaa agreed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a software question better suited for superuser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a similar dark theme.  Unfortunately, the background colour of the pasteboard is not styleable separately from the colour of the page. You can use `File` > `Document Properties` and "Background Colour" option to set a different colour, but it affects both the pasteboard and the page.

There is a workaround however. If you change the background to a grey colour in the Document Properties, you can add a rectangle filled white to cover the page - set the width and height same as the page dimensions, and the x and y co-ordinates to 0.  Then lock that layer, perhaps rename it "Background", and add a new layer.  Then you could save this as your default template.  In Windows, save the document named default.svg in the folder at `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\inkscape\templates`.

Each time you open a new document or start the application, Inkscape will load the default.svg

The downside is if you choose a different page size, you will have to edit the white filled rectangle to match the new page size.

Example:

[image: Example of Changing pasteboard colour in Inkscape]

Comment: @RamIyer Another downside to this workaround is to remember if you are outputting PNG images or final SVGs with a transparent background you may need to hide the background layer, or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution also here https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1210455/

download the 'default.svg' and follow their instruction:
To get dark background of canvas put "default.svg" in "~/.config/inkscape/templates" 

It works ;)

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found a better dark theme for Inkscape 0.92.4,
it’s based on latest GIMP dark theme, check it out!

http://bit.ly/darkinkscapetheme

[image]

Comment: It seems interesting, did you realize it by yourself? Can you please use an unobfuscated link?

Comment: It's a port of the GIMP dark theme, with some minor cleanup and changes, you can read about it on my blog [https://simonsoftwareselection.blogspot.com/2019/04/dark-theme-for-inkscape-0924.html](https://simonsoftwareselection.blogspot.com/2019/04/dark-theme-for-inkscape-0924.html) or download directly from [https://mega.nz/#!Yt0m2SSa!bARPJ5NTDj1sF6ysufm2shPR_MIuM1gHoGF_iTZMLTA](https://mega.nz/#!Yt0m2SSa!bARPJ5NTDj1sF6ysufm2shPR_MIuM1gHoGF_iTZMLTA)